# headless task in expo managed

Tags: react-native, expo

I am intressted in creating a task/process that run forever as long as the app is not closed

should continue running even in background.

some thing similar to this
[react-native-background-actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-actions) but for expo managed

now I tried using `expo-task-manager` but it only run at time interval and also only when in background.

I need my service to handle file operation and other things endlessly and this could not do with expo or at least I am not understanding how.

here is the code I tried but then read the docs and know that it will not work.

```
import * as BackgroundFetch from "expo-background-fetch";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";

const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = "background-fetch";

TaskManager.defineTask(
  BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK,
  async () => {
    const now = Date.now();

    console.log(
      `Got background fetch call at date: ${new Date(
        now
      ).toISOString()}`
    );

    // Be sure to return the successful result type!
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult
      .NewData;
  }
);

// 2. Register the task at some point in your app by providing the same name,
// and some configuration options for how the background fetch should behave
// Note: This does NOT need to be in the global scope and CAN be used in your React components!
async function registerBackgroundFetchAsync() {
  return BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(
    BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK,
    {
      minimumInterval: 60 * 15, // 15 minutes
      stopOnTerminate: false, // android only,
      startOnBoot: true // android only
    }
  );
}

// 3. (Optional) Unregister tasks by specifying the task name
// This will cancel any future background fetch calls that match the given name
// Note: This does NOT need to be in the global scope and CAN be used in your React components!
async function unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync() {
  return BackgroundFetch.unregisterTaskAsync(
    BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK
  );
}

export default class Service {
  static async register() {
    await registerBackgroundFetchAsync();
  }

  static async unregister() {
    await unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `react-native-background-actions` in your managed Expo app?

Answer (score 0):

Following the information [in this GH Issues comment](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions/issues/128#issuecomment-1551427467), it looks like you should be able to easily add `react-native-background-actions` to your managed Expo app using the provided Config Plugin code.

Comment: thx Will try it and let you know

Comment: I tried but `com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask` dose not register and get null when i try to start the service

Comment: Did you enable the permissions that the GH Issue talks about having to configure?

Comment: the issue is I am using this on android and cant run android with termux so no autolink